# Display only a particular category of items in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

I have created a ReactJS application which can display the data from an API.

Now I want to separate and display the data based on the category of the items.

My data in API is in this way

```
[
 {
  "Name": "Chicken pizza",
  "Category": "Pizza",
  "Type": "non-veg",
  "Price": 376,
  "id": "1"
 },
{
    "Name": "Oreo Milkshake",
    "Category": "Shakes",
    "Type": "veg",
    "Price": 130,
    "id": "9"
  }
]
```

So whenever I click on Pizza it should show only the items with "Category": "Pizza" and the same with the "Category": "Shakes" based on click function.

How can I achieve the functionality I want to implement on my application based on the requirements I have.

Below is my code for App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const App = () => {

    /*Toggle sidemenu start*/

    const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);

    const toggleTab = (index) =>{
        setToggleState(index);
    }

    /*Toggle sidemenu end*/

    /* API Data start */

    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
          try {
            const response = await fetch('https://63b040676a74151a1bbcf341.mockapi.io/restaurantmenu')
            const data = await response.json();
            setData(data);
            console.log("data")
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);

    /* API Data end */

  return (
    
    <div className='main-content'>
        <div className='restaurant-card'>
            <div className='image'>
                <img src='/images/kfc.png'/>
            </div>
            <div className='restaurant-details'>
                <h2>KFC</h2>
                <p>Abids, Hyderabad</p>
                <p><img src='/images/rating.png'/><span>4.5 Rating | 09:00 A.M - 11:00 P.M</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='item-category'>
            <h3>Categories</h3>
            <ul>
                <li className={toggleState === 1 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(1)}>Pizza</li>
                <li className={toggleState === 2 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(2)}>Bread</li>
                <li className={toggleState === 3 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(3)}>Shakes</li>
                <li className={toggleState === 4 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(4)}>Ice Cream</li>
                <li className={toggleState === 5 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(5)}>Cakes</li>
                <li className={toggleState === 6 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(6)}>Juices</li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
        <div className='item-list'>
            <div className="box">
                <input type="text" className="search-input" placeholder="Search for dishes"/>
                <img src='/images/search.png'/>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                {
                    data 
                    ? 
                        (
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                {data.map(item =>
                                    <div>
                                        <h2>{item.Category}</h2>
                                        <div className='items' key={item.id}>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>{item.Type}</li>
                                                <li>{item.Name}</li>
                                                <li>₹ {item.Price}</li>
                                                <div className='hr'></div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        ) 
                    : 
                        (<div>Loading...</div>)
                }
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And this is my sandbox link if you want any further info:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-wave-9b528h?file=/src/App.js

Guide me through the problem which I have confronted with whatever the ideas or the solutions you have which can help me overcome this.

I want to display the data by using an OnClick function in the sidemenu to display the different categories I have in my API and change the data based on category.

Answer (score 1):

update toggle state function

```
 const toggleTab = (index,name) => {
setToggleState(index);
const filteredArray = mainArray.filter((item) =>item.Category ===name)
setData(filteredArray)
```

};

and write every category name inside function
like

```
            onClick={() => toggleTab(1,'Pizza')}
```

Comment: I have implemented your method in my code but I'm facing an issue that is whenever I toggle to other category in the list for example Pizza to Bread then all others data is not rendered while toggling and at end my data is not at all visible unless refreshing. Is it because of the use of useEffect.

Comment: take one another state    const [mainArray, setMainArray] = useState([]);
and setMainArray when api load from useEffect.  check this link i update code on sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sinoussi-2m7xdl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That had worked fine and only think is on page load the whole data in the API is loading for Pizza, is there anything I can do to make only the category gets loaded.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-http-k7kek4 check this code

Comment: Finally can you tell how can I show the category name of the loaded data on the top of loaded data. For example if the pizza is active the  Pizza as the header, Bread is selected then Bread as Heading on top of the list.

Comment: please refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_forms.asp when first time use effect call that time update input text state value to "pizza" when click on anoter item that time update state inside toggleTab